# change text of radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

So I want to change the text of my radio button in JavaScript. .innerHTML seems to be changing the value in inspect elements but it never changes the shown text Option1a.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="Signup.php">
Username:<input name="CreateUsername" type="text" id="CreateUsername"><p>
Password:<input name="CreatePassword" type="password" id="CreatePassword">
email:<input name="CreateEmail" type="text" id="CreateEmail">
<input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option1" id="Option1">Option1a</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option2" id="Option2">Option2a</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option3" id="Option3">Option3a</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option4" id="Option4">Option4a</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option5" id="Option5">Option5a</input><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="signup">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CaptchaImg()
{
document.getElementById("CaptchaImg").src=Img;
document.getElementById("Option1").value=Option1;
document.getElementById("Option2").innerHTML = "aab";

}
</script>
```

Comment: Please do not edit your questions into different questions like this. It's not fair to those who have spent effort answering the existing question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the attribute. Not the innerHTML of the element. If you use your current method, it's going to set the innerHTML of the entire element when what you want to do is only update/change the value attribute. So your element is an input with the ID of Option# that has an attribute called value. Therefore you don't want to update anything else within the element except for the value attribute. You can do this by using the `.setAttribute("attribute", "value");` property.

```
document.getElementById("Option1").setAttribute("value", "The New Value");
```

Comment: but that is not the problem I want to change the text that the user sees inside the <input> tag. the value is already set with the .value i function CaptchaImg. I want to change Option1a.

Comment: Your question is asking how to change the VALUE of your radio button. Not the text.

Answer (score 0):

This works: Just add a label component for each of the String that you have embedded in the radio button. and change the value of the Label.Code below

```
form name="form1" method="post" action="Signup.php">Username:
<input name="CreateUsername" type="text" id="CreateUsername">
<p>Password:
    <input name="CreatePassword" type="password" id="CreatePassword">email:
    <input name="CreateEmail" type="text" id="CreateEmail">
    <input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option1" id="Option1" onclick="CaptchaImg();" > <label id="lbl">Option1a</label></input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option2" id="Option2">Option2a</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option3" id="Option3">Option3a</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option4" id="Option4">Option4a</input>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Captcha" value="Option5" id="Option5">Option5a</input>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="signup">
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function CaptchaImg()
 {
 document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = "aab";

 }    
 </script>
 </form>
```